# Getting SAXParser to ignore escape characters

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, saxparser

I am using sax parser to parse an xml file. It works perfectly except for when it comes across escape characters. Below is a the text in my xml file that I am trying to parse:

```
<line id='1'><![CDATA[Samantha saves 60&cent; on Thursday.]]></line>
<line id='2'><![CDATA[She saves 30&cent; on Friday.]]></line>
```

The result I get is: Samantha saves 60&"cent; on Thursday.She saves 30&"cent; on Friday.

How can I get my parser to ignore the & symbol? Is this possible?

EDIT: The above result is without the quotation marks. I dont want to have the & symbol after the number 60.

Comment: Why do you want to "ignore" the & symbol? And if you really want it, can you just encode the resulting string again?

Answer (score 0):

The CDATA tags are telling the parser that all characters within the CDATA sections are to be interpreted literally, that is, they represent themselves. So `&` within CDATA is not a special character; there are no escape sequences within CDATA. If you want to use entity references like `&cent;` then you shouldn't be using CDATA. What purpose are the CDATA tags fulfilling otherwise? Just get rid of them.